# try except open file python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open file and look for values. If the value doesn't exist, the program will display error message and quit, otherwise will return the value. If the file does not exist, it will handle the IOError. Here is my code snippet

```
def findValue(value):
    try:
        myfile = open(file, "r")
        try:
            for line in myfile:
                if value in line:
                    line = do_something
                    return line
        finally:
            myfile.close()

    except IOError:
        print "File does not exist!"
        sys.exit()

    except None as e:
        print "Value not found in file"
        sys.exit()
```

When the value does not exist, I will always get None, I guess am missing something here but can't see it! Any tips?

Comment: Python is case-sensitive:  `value` and `Value` are different.

Comment: Ok I fixed it as I have it in my code and actually I am looking for something else and value here to show example, in my code it has different parameter name :)

Comment: You need no try/except for this code snippet. First, take the good habit of opening your files using `with` statement : https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement. Second, since you return any line found, you can be sure no value is found if the control reaches the end of the for loop thus no try/catch needed there either.

Comment: Guys I do use with as well :) I just didn't want to copy and clean my code, I basically wrote fast a new one that resembles the logic am doing! Thanks

Comment: Do you not want `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`next`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) which raises a [**`StopIteration`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) exception if it doesn't find anything:

```
try:
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        return next(line for line in myfile
                    if value in line)
except StopIteration:
    print "Value not found in file"
```

Comment: lovely Peter! Exactly what am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is worthwhile understanding why the original stub code has a problem.

```
try:                                                                             
            for line in myfile:                                                          
                if value in line:                                                        
                    line = "found line"                                                  
                    return line
```

This returns `line` if `line` is found.  But what happens if `line` is not found? After iterating through `myfile` and `value` hasn't been found no error is generated so you will not trigger the `except` clause. Your `findvalue()` will implicitly return `None`. A minor tweek to your code fixes the issue: add a `return` not found string:

```
for line in myfile:                                                          
    if value in line:                                                        
        line = "found line"                                                  
        return line                                                          
return "Value not found in file" #or print this out. If you print this out rather than return a value the function will implicitly return a None.
```

and remove the `except None as e:` block

If you really want to raise an error then replace `return "Value not found in file"` with `raise ValueError` and replace `except None as e` with `except ValueError as e`.

Comment: You got up vote because it does the trick as well :) but I was looking for something using exception! Thanks

Comment: My last paragraph shows how to use exception here: i.e first `raise` the error and then you can catch it with `except`.

Answer (score 0):

A `for...else` flow might be useful here, it lets you execute code in the case the for loop has reached its end ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

def findValue(value):
    with open('test_file', "r") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            if value in line:
                #line = do_something
                return line
        else:
            raise ValueError, "Value not found in file"

print findValue('a')
findValue('z')
```

Test file content:

```
$ cat test_file 
abc
def
```

Script output:

```
$ ./test_script2.py
abc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_script2.py", line 16, in <module>
    findValue('z')
  File "./test_script2.py", line 11, in findValue
    raise ValueError, "Value not found in file"
ValueError: Value not found in file
```

And of course, if you replace 'test_file' by a non-existing file, python will raise a `IOError`.

Comment: with try except I still can handle the IOError. For example if the file doesn't exist. The program write logs file and it should be comprehensive enough. Thanks anyway